# Lock multiple tables with aliases doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I have tried to write some queries to insert some values in 3 tables in my database by creating 3 temporary tables(not CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE..) and then transferring the data to original tables. In doing so I want to lock the tables because one of the tables will contain,among other values, the last index values of the other tables.
I've tried locking the tables and their aliases but I still got the error:

> Table 'table_one_1' was not locked with LOCK TABLES.Below is a
>   modified, for simplicity, sample of the code .

What am i doing wrong?

```
UPDATED:
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS anx_name_tmp;CREATE TABLE anx_name_tmp LIKE anx_name;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS proc_name_tmp;CREATE TABLE proc_name_tmp LIKE proc_name;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS proc_anx_tmp;CREATE TABLE proc_anx_tmp LIKE proc_anx;
    LOCK TABLES proc_anx WRITE, proc_anx as proc_anx_1 READ ,proc_name WRITE,proc_name as proc_name_1 READ, anx_name WRITE,anx_name as anx_name_1 READ, proc_anx_tmp WRITE, proc_anx_tmp as proc_anx_tmp_1 READ ,proc_name_tmp WRITE,proc_name_tmp as proc_name_tmp_1 READ, anx_name_tmp WRITE,anx_name_tmp as anx_name_tmp_1 READ ;
    INSERT INTO anx_name_tmp(anx_name,version,anx_full_name,code) VALUES ('demo_1cOAHfl.docx','nc,a','','');
    INSERT INTO proc_name_tmp(proc_den,version,proc_full_name,code) VALUES ('demo_px5MiBh.pdf','nc,a','xbsj','False');
    INSERT INTO proc_anx_tmp(proc_id,anx_id,date_proc_anx,proc_id_orig,proc_anx_united,proc_category_id,user_log_id,change_req_id) VALUES ((SELECT proc_id +1 FROM proc_name as proc_name_1 ORDER BY proc_id DESC LIMIT 1),(SELECT anx_id +1 FROM anx_name as anx_name_1 ORDER BY anx_id DESC LIMIT 1),'2019-06-19',(SELECT proc_id +1 FROM proc_name as proc_name_1 ORDER BY proc_id DESC LIMIT 1),(SELECT proc_anx_id +1 FROM proc_anx as proc_anx_1 ORDER BY proc_anx_id DESC LIMIT 1),'3','5','0');

    ALTER TABLE anx_name_tmp CHANGE COLUMN anx_id anx_id INT(11) NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY ;UPDATE anx_name_tmp SET anx_id = 0 ;
    INSERT INTO anx_name SELECT * FROM anx_name_tmp as anx_name_tmp_1;
    ALTER TABLE proc_name_tmp CHANGE COLUMN proc_id proc_id INT(11) NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY ;UPDATE proc_name_tmp SET proc_id = 0 ;
    INSERT INTO proc_name SELECT * FROM proc_name_tmp as proc_name_tmp_1;ALTER TABLE proc_anx_tmp CHANGE COLUMN proc_anx_id proc_anx_id INT(11) NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY ;UPDATE proc_anx_tmp SET proc_anx_id = 0 ;
    INSERT INTO proc_anx SELECT * FROM proc_anx_tmp as proc_anx_tmp_1;
    UNLOCK TABLES
```

This is the actual code.
I am using InnoDB storage. 
I was reading that I can use `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` but I am not sure how and if it achieves what I am looking for: To lock the tables from which I am taking their primary keys and store it to a third table.

Comment: *"Below is a modified, for simplicity, sample of the code "* See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) you should also be providing example data and expected results..

Comment: It is the exact code, except the name of the tables and the fields. Also the values are not included.The code works very fine,if i exclude the LOCK and UNLOCK parts.

Comment: Your sample code does not work. While you can use pseudocode, it prevents anyone, including you, from relatively simply test it for correctness. At least the locks should represent what you are doing. You are locking the same table/table alias several times, which is not allowed (e.g. `table_one read,table_one Write`). Since your problem is very likely an error in your actual lock statement, replacing it by something that doesn't even work is not helping. (I suspect that you replaced 2 of your original tables with the same name)

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you are "required" to give a  Reproducible example (which includes example data and expected results) without this question is simply unclear and will be most likely not answerd and most likely will be voteclosed because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your intention using aliases is right, you still have to uphold [the rule](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)

> You cannot refer to a locked table multiple times in a single query using the same name. Use aliases instead, and obtain a separate lock for the table and each alias

This includes using an alias twice, which you are doing in

```
INSERT INTO proc_anx_tmp (...) VALUES ( 
  (SELECT proc_id +1 FROM proc_name as proc_name_1 ORDER BY proc_id DESC LIMIT 1),
  ...
  (SELECT proc_id +1 FROM proc_name as proc_name_1 ORDER BY proc_id DESC LIMIT 1)
  ... );
```

Replace one of those aliases. Since you are not actually using `proc_name` without an alias in this query, and you (write-)locked the unaliased table, you can just remove one of those aliases.

Comment: Btw: I am not entirely sure what you are doing with that query. It looks like you want to get the autoincrement values into a gapless order. This is not something you should need/want to do, autoincrement ids are not intended to be gapless, just unique, and you should not expect them to be.